# Vue not displaying text in curly braces in WP template

Tags: wordpress, vue.js

I'm just getting up to speed with Vue.js as a total newbie. I have no console errors, but the text is not displaying in curly braces just for a basic test.

I'm in a WordPress environment and all I'm doing is creating a custom template to run a basic test displaying text via Vue. In my HTML file I include Vue from the CDN, then run this script inline.

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
  message: 'Hello Vue!'
},
mounted: function(){
    console.log("WP Vue Theme!");
}
```

})

HTML is:

```
<div id="app">

    <p>Value of the input is {{message}}</p>

</div>
```

And the output that displays is:

Value of the input is {{message}}.

In the console I typed app.message and I do get "Hello Vue!". But for some reason, it's not resolving in the HTML.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `app.$el` in the console, check it's the element you're expecting.

Comment: Shouldn't `app.message` in the console be `Hello Vue!` rather than `WP Vue Theme!`?

Comment: I corrected my description that yes, the console displays "Hello Vue!" not as I originally posted. I also checked app.$el and it displays "<div></div>" in the console. Should it be "<div id="app">"?

Comment: Try hovering your mouse cursor over the `<div>` shown in the console, see what gets highlighted in the viewport. Failing that, try setting `app.$el.innerHTML = 'Hello'`, see where that shows up. My suspicion is that you have multiple elements with the same id. Note that the id might be removed by Vue, it depends on exactly what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. If I hover over the `<div>` element, nothing pops up. When I do `app.$el.innerHTML = 'Hello'` the console just prints "Hello" and the site content doesn't change. I also tried changing the id from `app` to `app-test` just to make sure it wasn't a dupe id, but got the same results. Hmmm...

Comment: are you sure you calling `new Vue(...)` after the html part. looks like the $el is not the right element. also check if you have another div with id of "app"

Comment: If you try to create the Vue instance before the element `app` is in the DOM then it will use an empty `<div>` instead. However, it should also log a console error. Assuming that error is being suppressed for some reason, you could investigate further in a number of ways: 1. Try wrapping your code in a timer. 2.Add in a `debugger` statement just before `new Vue`. 3. Try grabbing the element with `document.getElementById('app')` just before the `new Vue` to see whether it is accessible. I'm not suggesting you try all three at once but any one of these may provide an explanation.

Comment: eli chen, you nailed it! Thank you and to skirtle as well. I put the `new Vue` statement after the HTML and it worked! Is this in the Vue documentation somewhere I missed? I walked through a video tutorial and it didn't say anything about the order. I'm also under a WordPress umbrella enqueuing javascript/vue files that, unless specified to enqueue in the footer, will automatically run in the header before the HTML appears in the DOM. So I guess anyone using WP and Vue scripts would have to enqueue the custom Vue script in the footer?

Answer (score 0):

Per Eli Chen's comment, this is the answer. I had the script running above the HTML:

> are you sure you calling new Vue(...) after the html part. looks like the $el is not the right element. also check if you have another div with id of "app" – eli chen 1 hour ago